# How do I stop my carrots from sticking up too high being nibbled from the top?

Tags: vegetables, pest-control, seeds, root-vegetables, carrots

I have some purple carrots and there growing excellently. But after a couple of months, they started to stick up 2-3 cm above the ground with one eaten, so I pulled them out before anymore were eaten. They were all quite short ranging between 3-9 cm. I planted my seeds around 3.5 cm deep.

I did some research and it said two things; One was to plant the seeds deeper, and the second was to put a damp sheet over where you planted the carrots and poke holes where you planted the carrots. Would these work?

Comment: Why not just cover them up with some additional soil when they start to poke above the soil you have planted them.  Give the entire row enough soil to keep the carrots from being exposed, but not enough to cover the leaves.

Comment: Thanks! I`ll try that!